# how to select arguments from text file in bash and loop over them

Tags: bash

I have a text file that contains the following format below and I wanted to write a bash script that stores the column (adastatus,type,bodycomponent) names into a variable say x1.

```
# col_name              data_type               comment

adastatus         string                  None
type              string                  None
bodycomponent   string                  None
bodytextlanguage      string                  None
copyishchar       string                  None
```

Then for each of the columns names in x1 I want to run a loop

```
alter table tabelname change x1(i) x1(i) DOUBLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `cut -f1 yourfile.txt`
do
    SQL="alter table tablename change $i $i DOUBLE"
    sql_command $SQL
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$1 !~ /^#/ {if ($1) print $1}' in.txt | \
   xargs -I % echo "alter table tabelname change % % DOUBLE"
```

Replace `echo` with the command needed to run the `alter` command (from @Severun's answer it sounds like `sql_command`).

- using `awk`, matches only input lines that do no start with `#` (except for leading whitespace) and are non-empty, then returns the first whitespace-separated token, i.e., the 1st column value for each line.
- `xargs` invokes the target command once for each column name, substituting the column name for `%` - note that `%` as a placeholder was randomly chosen via the `-I` option.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read col1 _ _
do
    [[ "$col1" =~ \#.* ]] && continue    # skip comments
    [[ -z "$col1" ]] && continue         # skip empty lines
    echo alter table tabelname change ${col1}\(i\) ${col1}\(i\)
done < input.txt
```

Output:

```
$ ./c.sh 
alter table tabelname change adastatus(i) adastatus(i)
alter table tabelname change type(i) type(i)
alter table tabelname change bodycomponent(i) bodycomponent(i)
alter table tabelname change bodytextlanguage(i) bodytextlanguage(i)
alter table tabelname change copyishchar(i) copyishchar(i)
```

Change `echo` to a more appropriate command.